# POWER BI DAX measure with filter, condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

please could you help me with the below measure.

My table : query 1
The column “Indicator” contains unique number like , 119 .
MertricNumerator is my calculated filed by choosing option from slicer
I want to get the result for Indicator number 119, then IF sum( numerator) is blank OR 0 or null “No Data” if
Sum(numerator) < 5 show “low count of data” else SUM(Query1[Metric_Numerator])
Many Thanks

> { MEASURE= IF( SELECTEDVALUE(Query1[indicator])=119 &&
> SUM(Query1[Metric_Numerator])<5, "Low count number", IF(
> SELECTEDVALUE(Query1[indicator])=119 &&
> SUM(Query1[Metric_Numerator])=0
> ||ISBLANK(SUM(Query1[Metric_Numerator])), "No Data",
> SUM(Query1[Metric_Numerator]) )) }

Comment: What error does it produce when you run this code?

Comment: this is Error Message:
****MdxScript(Model) (24, 127) Calculation error in measure 'Query1'[Tooltip]: DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type Integer. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.****

Comment: Hello Nikki, Could you please share some data of Column values ? Error message tells it all "You can't compare apples with pears". Please check the compatibility of column data types.

Comment: thanks for the clue the problem is Indicator column format is text and numerator format is general is that why get error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 things that doesn't allow you to get expected result.

1 - your second `IF` expression is `a && b || c`. DAX engine doesn't understand how do you want to evaluate this expression - like `(a && b) || c` or like  `a && (b || c)`.  DAX will evaluate the expression as `(a && b) || c`, because && has higher priority level. Also, the expression is evaluated in the order that operators appears in the expression, from left to right. So, supply the expression with brackets.

2 - you want to get different data types from one expression - a string or number. For a measure it's Ok, but for a calc column it will be an error, because the column data type can not be variant. It's needed to be corrected.

3 - Query1[indicator] is a text, then the value you are comparing with should be a text also. So cover it with ""

Please, check the corrected measure.

```
MEASURE = 
    IF(
       SELECTEDVALUE(Query1[indicator])="119" && SUM(Query1[Metric_Numerator])<5
       ,"Low count number"
       ,IF(
            SELECTEDVALUE(Query1[indicator])="119" 
           && 
           (
            SUM(Query1[Metric_Numerator])=0 
           ||
            ISBLANK(SUM(Query1[Metric_Numerator]))
            )
           ,"No Data"
           ,"" & SUM(Query1[Metric_Numerator]) 
        )
)
```

This can work, but I would use `SWITCH()` instead.

Comment: Hi Milk thanks for the correction great point but still can not get it right for the data type, Indicator column format is text and numerator format is general is that why get error message.

Comment: Hi @Nikki, I altered the answer. You get the error, because the value  119 is a number, it should be text if Query1[indicator] is a text - "119"

Comment: @Mik why didnt you use SWITCH() then ))) ?

Comment: Hi @UmutK, glad to hear from you. I thought that it would be better to explain why the measure  didn't work. This will let OP get a better understanding of coding.

Comment: @Mik hi again...  your effort to explain the reasons and corrections of the present codes are great. however, on the other hand, i would love to hear to alternative codes which works faster and also learn something new... )))